# Zero division error even with If statement

Tags: python

My teacher told me to use an if statement to get rid of the Zero Division error but all I see in the internet is function that counters it not an if statement.

```
#date January 22, 2018
#title Finding Slope Of A Line

x1 = input ("Give a value for x1 that is less than ten: ")
x2 = input ("Give a value for x2 that is less than ten: ")
y1 = input ("Give a value for y1 that is less than ten: ")
y2 = input ("Give a value for y2 that is less than ten: ")

x1 = int(x1)
x2 = int(x2)
y1 = int(y1)
y2 = int(y2)

y = y2 - y1
x = x2 - x1

if x == 0:
    print("Undefined")

yx = y/x
yx = int (slope)

if yx != 0:
    print ("%d"%yx)
if yx == 0:
    print ("Undefined")
```

Comment: What is `slope` supposed to be?

Comment: I guess it is `slope = y/x` and then `yx = int (slope)`. And also it will be better if you cahnge the datatype of slope to float.

Comment: A print doesn't end the execution, so it keeps running through past the if statement. Either use an else statement or kill the program in some other way.

Comment: Ahhh yeah. Somebody answered this question already. I learned that a print doesn't end the execution. I will use else statement next time. Thanks for the info. I got rid of yx = int (slope). I was just making extra sure that I know slope is a integer and not a string. Well I now know it's an integer because it's not enclosed in parentheses and is result of division with integers. Now how do I close the question?

Comment: You can delete the question.  There is a flag under the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an `if` statement, but you're not `return`ing anything, the code after it will still be executed.
You can avoid that by wrapping the rest of your related code in an `else` as mentioned by @Stephen Rauch..

FYI: *Common mistake while beginning to learn programming,* `print` *and* `return` *are* **not** *the same.*

Alternatively, you can handle the `ZeroDivisionError` using a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

```
......
y = y2 - y1
x = x2 - x1

try:
    # not sure what this does
    yx = y/x
    yx = int (slope) # I'm assuming you have slope defined somewhere
    print ("%d"%yx)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ("Undefined")
```

NB: This only handles for ZeroDivisionError. For more info on error handling, visit the link above

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I don't know how my teacher will accept this though. I will tell him I got it from stack overflow as he said that we should try to learn from internet too. :D

Comment: @StephenRauch has a good point! I am only assuming that you forgot to add the definition of `slope` to the snippet you posted @CateDoge

Comment: Yes. I just added this to my previous code. :D Also I'm at a loss on how to close this subject. I can't delete it because people have put time and effort here.

Answer (score 1):

An `else` would useful here:

```
if x == 0:
    print("Undefined")
else: 
    yx = y/x
    yx = int (slope)

    if yx != 0:
        print ("%d"%yx)
    else:
        print ("Undefined")
```

Comment: I added that to the previous code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the instruction. Write a program prompting the user to enter x and y-coordinates of two points on the
XY-plane, that is x1, y1, x2, and y2. The program calculates the slope of the line with formula (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).

Comment: As an FYI: The statement *it still doesn't work* is not terribly illuminative.

Answer (score 1):

As @Stephen Rauch mentioned you can chose to go with else block or you can put `!=` check in if block (if negative values are allowed) :

```
if x != 0:
    yx = y/x
    rest of your code
```

Here are some examples.

We took x equals to 0:

[image: with x == 0]

We took x not equal to 0:

[image: with x != 0]

Comment: I'm sorry but we're not there yet. We're at the basics right now. :D Thanks for answering though.

Comment: This is also basic mate. You are checking for "equal to" and != is "not equal to". or put code you want to execute if x is "not equal to 0" in the "else" block.

Comment: please see the images, hope that helps